# Microsoft AD Authentication node js Library

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, msal.js, passport-azure-ad

I am developing a nodejs application in which I want to use Microsoft AD oath2 flow. I looked into Microsoft's official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries) and found that they list two libraries -

1. msal-node
2. passport-azure-ad

I need help selecting the library which will best serve my needs. I need to -

- perform authentication
- protect some apis via token verification
- expose all the apis so that they can be tested externally
- call external web apis within my app

Also, the documentation says that "Acces web apis" is not possible with passport-azure-ad. What do they mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

I've used passport-azure-ad to handle Azure SSO in a complex login service which involved many different authentication protocols.

It worked perfectly fine to establish the client credential flow, in which the session is managed by the back-end.

The msal-node library is better to implement an implicit flow, in which an SPA gains access to a token which can then be used to obtain data from the identity provider.

Another way around it would be to use passport-azure-ad to handle the login, and then tie that in to a custom JWT generation system.

That would end up looking something like this:

```js
const passport = require('passport');
const OIDCStrategy = require('passport-azure-ad').OIDCStrategy;

const Token = require('Token.js');

settings = {
  azureDirectoryId: '',
  azureClientId: '',
  azureClientSecret: '',
  callbackUrl: 'https://example.com/auth/callback',
}

passport.use(new OIDCStrategy(
  {
    identityMetadata: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${settings.azureDirectoryId}/.well-known/openid-configuration`,
    clientID: settings.azureClientId,
    responseType: 'code id_token',
    responseMode: 'form_post',
    redirectUrl: settings.callbackUrl,
    clientSecret: settings.azureClientSecret,
    // ...additional settings if needed
  },
  (req, iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, done) => {
    process.nextTick(async () => {
      profile.accessToken = accessToken;
      profile.refreshToken = refreshToken;
      profile.token = Token.generate(profile);
      done(null, profile);
    });
  },
));

router.get('/auth/login', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', {
    response: res,
    resourceURL: null,
    customState: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10),
    failureRedirect: '/failure',
  })(req, res, next);
});

router.use('/auth/callback', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', {
    response: res,
    successRedirect: '/success',
    failureRedirect: '/failure',
  })(req, res, next);
});

router.get('/auth/success', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.user.token) {
    res.cookie('token', req.user.token);
    return res.redirect('https://example.com');
  }
  failure(req, res);
});

const failure = (req, res) => {
  req.session.destroy(() => {
    res.clearCookie('token', cookieSettings);
    res.redirect('https://example.com');
  });
};

router.get('/auth/failure', failure);
```

This way, sending the user to https://example.com/auth/login would start off the process of authentication via passport. Once completed, you'd generate a JWT with the information returned from the identity provider (`Token.generate(profile);`), store that token as a cookie, and redirect the user back to the homepage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used msal-node to get access and id tokens. I added the id token to a cookie and then verified it in all protected end points using jsonwebtoken nodejs package.